# QNEAT3 OD Matrix distance incorrect?

Tags: qgis-plugins, shortest-path, distance-matrix, network-analysis

I am currently working on calculating the distances between all pairs of NUTS-2 regions in a road network.

To accomplish this I am using the QNEAT3 plugin. It worked very efficiently and I was exceedingly pleased by it. However, upon closer inspection I found that the distance between point A and itself was 50 hours in the network.

[image]

I am not sure why this is such a long journey time and whether this indicates that I have set the algorithm up incorrectly.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: This could be related to a bug I fixed in QNEAT3 - you can download the latest version as ZIP from https://github.com/root676/QNEAT3 and replace the QNEAT3 folder in your QGIS plugins folder with this newer version.

Comment: I tried installing via ZIP but QNEAT3 does not show up in the toolbox. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The error message displayed is the following                     "Couldn't load plugin 'QNEAT3-master' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

"

Comment: You have to unzip the folder and then replace the old folder with the unzipped one. The content/structure of the new folder should match the old QNEAT3 folder (including file/directory names).

Comment: Thanks, that worked, the points are now NA, as they should be. Selected other connections on the map are now NA as well, presumably since they are too far from a network node. Where can I set the maximum distance to/from the network?

Comment: Great to hear! You cannot currently set the maximum distance in this algorithm. If OD-pairs are missing, they either refer to the same point or to unreachable points in the network (eg. no connectivity).